# Не работает xdebug в PHPSTORM

Tags: php, сервер, веб-сервер, xdebug, расширения

По-простому говоря не подтягиваются значения из php.ini в xdebug.

```
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"

phpnifo()
```

[image: phpinfo]

При этом не смотря на то, что в php.ini они были заданы, в phpinfo() они следующие:

```
xdebug.idekey=no value
xdebug.remote_enable=Off
```

Comment: прокинул значения в xdebug.ini, все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прокинул значения в xdebug.ini, все заработало